# Short animation of a spaceship running against time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship

It's basically a man riding a spaceship at full speed thru a canyon in a random rocky planet.. Then he gets out and RUNS holding a pod into a big building, jumping over bodies stuck in time, only to slowly come to a halt right before placing the pod in a machine with only space for one pod left. After stopping, the time loop comes in and he's seen riding the spaceship again at full speed.

Now, I saw it maybe 6 months ago and I've been looking for many days without ANY success..... My head hurts

Comment: CGI animation? Hand drawn? Western/Anime?

Comment: Do you remember roughly how long it was?

Answer (score 4):

This is a short CG film called "Initium", I originally saw it on io9 [here](http://io9.com/this-short-time-travel-movie-packs-insane-visuals-and-1071211097) (the article gives some background on it, apparently it was a student film), but you can also see it on youtube here: